# How can I import a locally stored module via absolute path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a file `file.py` which I want to import a local module. A server I do some work on doesn't allow me to install modules so I am trying to include them in my projects locally to reference. I have downloaded the necessary modules but I'm unable to install them.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sys import exit

try:
    import "/modules/pandas"
    import "/modules/numpy"
except ImportError:
    print("Modules not found!")
    exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Modules loaded properly.")
    exit(0)
```

Above is the general idea of what I'm trying to do. My directory structure is like so:

```
parent/
-- file.py
-- modules/
-- -- pandas/
-- -- -- ...
-- -- -- __init__.py
-- -- -- ...
-- -- numpy/
-- -- -- ...
-- -- -- __init__.py
-- -- -- ...
```

How can I access these modules in this situation?

If it matters, the server is running Red Hat Linux and it does not have `pip`.

Comment: Can you use a virtualenv?

Comment: cant you just import them relatvily like `import modules.pandas`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle it doesn't seem to work. Using the code snippet I've provided, changing it to `import modules.pandas` still says "Modules not found!".

Comment: try `import parent.modules.pandas`, check `print(sys.path)` whether the parent path is listed or not. If not then include the parent path by `sys.path.insert(0,"Path/to/parent directory/")`

Comment: @Ratnesh the parent folder is indeed in `sys.path`, specifically `sys.path[0]`. Trying `import parent.modules.pandas` and `import sys.path[0].modules.pandas` also does not work.

Comment: @gator, why it does not have `pip`, please try `pip list`, as you have mentioned in your post

Comment: @Ratnesh it's controlled by my university. `pip list` yields `pip: command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried mimic similar setup in my local. I could able to get the result.

**fileStack.py**

```
import sys
try:
    import modules.pandas
    print("done!!")

except ImportError:
    print("Modules not found!")
    sys.exit(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Modules loaded properly.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Output:

```
done!!
Modules loaded properly.
```

Setup:
I have git clone the pandas source code from here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master/pandas My directory structure looks like this:

```
parent:
-- fileStack.py
-- modules
-- -- pandas
-- -- -- .github
-- -- --  pandas
-- -- -- -- __init__.py
```

Comment: I see. I copy/pasted `pandas/pandas`, because this is where the `__init__.py` is located. Instead I tried with the broader `pandas` directory and it works as intended.

Comment: What exactly is in the upper `pandas` folder that I needed, I wonder?

Comment: @gator, I just renamed it to the directory downloaded from git